# PyQGIS - Print Layout Legend. setLegendFilterByMapEnabled()

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I'm creating a legend in my print composer and only want "visible", or active, layers shown in the legend. This means I want only layers with the box checked in my layers panel.

Here is how I create my legend.

```
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle("Legend")
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
```

[Looking at the documentation for QgsLayoutItemLegend](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsLayoutItemLegend.html?highlight=qgslayoutitemlegend#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemLegend) there is a method: setLegendFilterByMapEnabled() whose description is: 
[image]

This leads me to believe if I do something like:

```
legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
```

My legend will only include "active" layers. But my legend still includes all layers, active and inactive.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to link the legend item to a map item in your layout which is an instance of the QgsLayoutItemMap class. So if you have done something like:

```
map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
layout.addItem(map)
```

link it with the legend before enabling the filtering:

```
legend.setLinkedMap(map) # pass a QgsLayoutItemMap object
legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
legend.refresh()
```

---

Alternatively, to collect checked layers from the project layer tree view and add those to your layout legend, you could do something like this:

```
lyrs_to_add = [l for l in QgsProject().instance().layerTreeRoot().children() if l.isVisible()]
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle('Legend')
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
group = legend.model().rootGroup()
group.clear()
for l in lyrs_to_add:
    if l.nodeType() == 0:
        subgroup = group.addGroup(l.name())
        checked = l.checkedLayers()
        for c in checked:
            subgroup.addLayer(c)
    elif l.nodeType() == 1:
        group.addLayer(l.layer())
layout.addItem(legend)
legend.adjustBoxSize()
legend.refresh()
```

This will maintain groups etc. but unfortunately it won't filter unchecked nodes for categorized or graduated layers (I still can't work out how to do that).

Comment: I completely misunderstood setLegendFilterByMapEnabled() so thank you for explaining that method. Also, this is amazing. You have really helped me out recently! Two questions I have: in your checked_lyrs list comprehension line, where did you get the .children() method from? I don't see it as a method in the QgsLayerTree class. I understand the children are the items in the Layer Tree. Or is this a generic method I can call on any object that contains multiple items? The same applies to: root.addLayer(lyr).  Shouldn't .addLayer be a method of QgsLayerTree?

Comment: Another question: in the legend.model().setRootGroup() line.  .model is a method of QgsLayoutItemLegend class which "returns the legend model" (that isn't very descriptive). and .setRootGroup is a method of QgsLayerTreeModel class. How can these be chained together like that? Apologies for the questions but I'm just trying to understand as best I can.

Comment: No problem @Erich Purpur. All your questions above which are causing your confusion are answered by class inheritance. I you look at the API Docs for a class (I find the C++ docs are actually more helpful for this), often you will see an inheritance diagram. Many classes inherit attributes and methods from other classes. So calling `.children()` on a `QgsLayerTree` object is possible because it is an inherited method from the `QgsLayerTreeNode` class. Likewise, `addLayer()` is an inherited method from `QgsLayerTreeGroup` and `setRootGroup()` is inherited from the `QgsLayerTreeModel` class

Comment: Link to C++ Docs: https://qgis.org/api/annotated.html Example of class inheritance diagram: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTree.html Also, if you scroll down the documentation you will often see the "Additional Inherited Members" for a class.

Comment: Great, thanks again.  I've been looking only at the python documentation. I'll be sure to reference the c++ documentation in the future.